# How can I apply convolution over the undefined shape in Keras or Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

With Keras, I defined,

`conv = Convolution2D(num_filters, ws, ws)(x)`,

where I have the shape of `x` be `(1, ?, 10, 1)`

And I met the problem with

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Since the convolutional weight matrices applied on each window of the 2D image share parameters, it is valid at least for me to do it without knowing the true dimension of the image.

Comment: which image ordering do you use?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko The tensorflow order

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Can I move a window across the shape `(?, 10)`

Comment: @xxx222 i stand corrected. Apparently tf does allow tensor shape to be computed at runtime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096225/how-to-understand-static-shape-and-dynamic-shape-in-tensorflow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process input of arbitrary size in your CNN define first layer as follows:

```
Convolution2D(num_filters, ws, ws, input_shape=(nb_channels, None, None))
```

Note that it takes much longer time to train a network with variable input size compared to fixed. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322286/training-a-fully-convolutional-neural-network-with-inputs-of-variable-size-takes).